# How to evaluate model performance of keras tuner.search?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm currently trying to visualise the performance of my prediction model by showing the val_mse in every epoch. The code that used to work for `model.fit()` doesn't work for `tuner.search()`. Can anyone provide me with some guide on this. Thank you.

Previous code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_model(history):
    hist = pd.DataFrame (history.history)
    hist['epoch'] = history.epoch
    
    plt.figure()
    plt.xlabel('Epoch')
    plt.ylabel('Mean Absolute Error')
    plt.plot(hist['epoch'], hist['mae'],
           label='Train Error')
    plt.plot(hist['epoch'], hist['val_mae'],
           label = 'Val Error')
    plt.legend()
    plt.ylim([0,20])
    plt.figure()
    plt.xlabel('Epoch')
    plt.ylabel('Mean Square Error')
    plt.plot (hist['epoch'], hist['mse'],
           label='Train Error')
    plt.plot (hist['epoch'], hist['val_mse'],
           label = 'Val Error')
    plt.legend()
    plt.ylim([0,400])
    
plot_model(history)
```

keras.tuner code:

```
history = tuner.search(x = normed_train_data,
             y = y_train,
             epochs = 200,
             batch_size=64,
             validation_data=(normed_test_data, y_test),
             callbacks = [early_stopping])
```

Answer (score 1):

Keras Tuner does not work that way!

There is more "KerasTuner"-friendly way of visualizing the training curves by using Tensorboard callback.

#### Define the tensorboard callback like this.

```
tensorboard_callback = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard("/content/tb_logs") # The logs will be written to "/content/tb_logs".
```

#### Modify you tuner.search() method like this.

```py
tuner.search(
    x = normed_train_data,
    y = y_train,
    epochs = 200,
    batch_size=64,
    validation_data=(normed_test_data, y_test),
    callbacks = [early_stopping, tensorboard_callback]
)
```

#### For running this in Python Notebook (.ipynb).

```
%load_ext tensorboard
%tensorboard --logdir /content/tb_logs
```

For more information visit: https://keras.io/guides/keras_tuner/visualize_tuning/

Answer (score 0):

Before using `tuner.search` to search the best model, you need to install and import `keras_tuner`:

```
!pip install keras-tuner --upgrade
import keras_tuner as kt
from tensorflow import keras
```

Then, define the hyperparameter (hp) in the model definition, for instance as below:

```
def build_model(hp):
  model = keras.Sequential()
  model.add(keras.layers.Dense(
      hp.Choice('units', [8, 16, 32]),  # define the hyperparameter
      activation='relu'))
  model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='relu'))
  model.compile(loss='mse')
  return model
```

Initialize the tuner:

```
tuner = kt.RandomSearch(build_model,objective='val_loss',max_trials=5)
```

Now, Start the search and get the best model by using `tuner.search`:

```
tuner.search(x = normed_train_data,
             y = y_train,
             epochs = 200,
             batch_size=64,
             validation_data=(normed_test_data, y_test),
             callbacks = [early_stopping])

best_model = tuner.get_best_models()[0]
```

Hence, Now you can use this `best_model` to train and evaluate the model with your dataset and will get a significant decrease in loss.

Please check [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/keras_tuner) link as a reference for more detail.